# AS3 smarter type definitons

Tags: actionscript-3, game-engine

I'm working on a component based engine in AS3 and I've got a function in game object that returns a component based on it's type:

```
gameObject.Has(Body); //This will return a reference to the gameobjects body component
```

The problem I'm having is accessing the component. To do so I have to do something like this:

```
Body(gameObject.Has(Body)).SetVelocity(5);
```

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Edit:

```
public function Has(type:Class):BaseComponent
{
    for each(var component:BaseComponent in m_components)
        if (component is type)
            return component;

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you currently have for the return type of Has()?

If you prefer to circumvent type checking. You can have your Has() method return type Object.

```
public function Has():Object{
  ...
  return anObject;
}

#then you can call any prop/method without throwing type errors.
gameObject.Has(Body).SetVelocity(5)
```

There is not however a nice way to maintain type checking without casting the var, which you're already doing in your example code.

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing that. I really wish AS3 has templates and preprocessor directives.

Comment: I was also thinking of writing an array of functions indexed by the type but that seems like over kill.

Comment: In AS3 it would be rare that I'd setup such a generic m_components array. I suppose its a case where you have many undeterminable objects that you're keeping track of or you're trying to write less code. If you want to make it easier on yourself for the case of Body, make a getter:  `public function get body():Body` to wrap and cast that item.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your issue is that you're trying to be overly generic in your implementation. This introduces two possible points of failure: on the "in" side, where you could potentially load in a BaseObject for your Body that is not a Body, and on the "out" side, where your gameObject could return an object that is not a Body (the fact that the current implementation is apparently type safe is not a given).

You know that any time you are calling what is essentially a *really* generic getter that you need it to be returning a specific type of object (because you'll be calling methods on it), so why not make life easier on yourself by just making the explicit getter and setter needed?

Or you could get **totally** ridiculous and genericize your BaseObject like:

```
gameObject.has(Body).callMethod('setVelocity').to(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

We are doing kind of the same thing in our project. But we have another approuch. We have a utility class in our ObjectUtility. The method returns all objects under a specific root object.

```
        public function collectObjectsByType(object:Object, type:Class, results:Array):void
    {

    }
```

I can just show the method struct.